# SQLite sub query, with variable number of inputs

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

Trying to build a SQL query for SQLite database which will take give subject name(s) and will return all matching rows irrespective of order of words in subject records. Following query works as expected for 2 inputs.

```
select name
from 
    (select name from students where tags like "%biology%") 
where 
    tags like "%physics%"
```

If 3 subject inputs are passed in as follows `Geo Math Zoo` above query has to be extended, through code (using Python in this case). Is there any better alternative to handle number of inputs cases in range of 9 to 10?

`Student` table:

```
Name    Sub
-------------------------------------------
S1      Biology Math Geo Physics
S2      Math Geo Physics
S3      Biology Geo Math Physics Zoo       -- should be in output
S4      Biology Physics Math Geo 
S5      Biology Zoo Math Geo               -- should be in output
```

Comment: Don't store multiple values in a string!  You want a separate table with one row per tag and per name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `OR` operator to search for multiple conditions:

```
select *
from students
where tags like "%biology%"
   or tags like "%physics%"
```

Comment: Thanks for pointer and SQL basics lesson (ashamed to miss this simple construct). I just added AND instead of OR, and it seems it gives expected output. Also this format of query is easy to create via code.